# C# asynchronous tasks training (turn-based simulation)

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I know embarassingly little about asynchronous programming in C#, so decided to start catching up. It would help me a lot if anyone checked this basic example I've created.

**Assumption**: we're creating a simulation where the time passes turn by turn with predefined minimal interval, e.g. 1 second. However, if any important calculations during the turn would take longer than this interval, next turn should not begin until they're done.

I would be grateful if you could tell me if there any visible issues, code smells, or if it can be optimized. I've read bad things about using `Task.Run`, but I don't really know how to tackle it better.

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var gameTurnsController = new GameTurnsController();
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        try
        {
            // Asynchronously wait for input to send cancellation token
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.ReadKey(true);
                cts.Cancel();
            });

            gameTurnsController.PassTurns(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cts.Token).Wait(cts.Token);
        }
        // It smells of controlling the execution flow through exception. Isn't there a better way to handle cancellation?
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Cancelled.");
            Environment.ExitCode = 0;
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine("Execution finished.");
    }
}
```

```
public class GameTurnsController
{
    public async Task PassTurns(TimeSpan interval, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Wait until both delay and calculation is finished
            await Task.WhenAll(Task.Delay(interval, cancellationToken), LongRunningOperation(cancellationToken));
        }
    }

    // expensive method example
    private async Task<long> LongRunningOperation(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            long result;
            // ...
            // expensive math operation that returns long value
            // ...
            return result;
        }, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

In the above code I've removed most of the logs and stopwatches for clarity.

Comment: What .NET and C# version are you using? I'm asking it because for example [async main](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main) is supported since C# 7.1

Comment: I'm using 7.0, but I know about `async main`. Do I get it right that the only change here would be awaiting the `PassTurns` call instead of using `.Wait` on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Wait` call is tricky.

- It throws by default `AggregateException` not `OperationCanceledException`.
- If you provide the `cancellationToken` to the `Wait` then it will throw an `OperationCanceledException`.
- The biggest problem with this approach is that it cancels **only** the `Wait` not the underlying task.

  - Please read this [article](https://lbadri.wordpress.com/2016/10/04/cancellationtoken-with-task-run-and-wait/) for more details.

So, if we switch to [async main](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main) then the application will not stop after user cancellation:

```cs
static async Task Main()
{
    var gameTurnsController = new GameTurnsController();
    var userRequestedCancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();

    try
    {
        _ = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please press any key to cancel");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            userRequestedCancellation.Cancel();
        });

        await gameTurnsController.PassTurns(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), userRequestedCancellation.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Cancelled.");
        Environment.ExitCode = 0;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Execution finished.");
}
```

- Because the underlying `LongRunningOperation` will not terminate.

  - (Let me use `Thread.Sleep(5000)` to simulate complex CPU bound operation)

```cs
private async Task<long> LongRunningOperation(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        long result;
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return result;
    }, cancellationToken);
}
```

- If I run this app and I press any key then it will not cancel the `LongRunningOperation` method that's why the output will be the `Execution finished.`.

### How to fix it?

By passing all the way long the cancellationToken:

```cs
private async Task<long> LongRunningOperation(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var job = Task.Run(() => LongRunningOperationInternal(cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
    return await job;
}

private long LongRunningOperationInternal(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    long result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        Thread.Sleep(1000); 
    }

    return result;
}
```

If need to do graceful cancellation then consider to use the following pattern:

```cs
if(cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
  //TODO: clean up whatever is needed

  cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
```

TL;DR: You need to check the cancellationToken at milestones/checkpoints to be able to truly cancel the whole application.

---

Might be an interesting read: [How to can non-cancelable async operations](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations/)