# c# make synchronization function waitable and cancelable

Tags: c#, async-await

I need to call some synchronization function and need they running in background and canbe canceled. So I write this:

```
private static async Task WaitSyncFunction(Action syncFunction,
    int timeoutMilliseconds,
    CancellationToken token)
{
    var syncFunctionTask = Task.Run(syncFunction);
    var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeoutMilliseconds, token);
    await Task.WhenAny(timeoutTask, syncFunctionTask).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (timeoutTask.IsCanceled) throw new TaskCanceledException();
        if (timeoutTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully) throw new TimeoutException();
        if (syncFunctionTask.IsFaulted) throw syncFunctionTask.Exception.InnerException;
    });
}
```

use it:

```
//...async method of button click event handler in window
cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
try
{
    await WaitSyncFunction(() => MySyncFunction(), 5000, cancelSource.Token);
    MessageBox.Show("Success!");
}
catch (TaskCanceledException) { MessageBox.Show("Canceled!"); }
catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show("Error! "+ ex.Message); }
//...
```

What risks may exist in codes, and is it anti-pattern?

============Edit============
Some improvements:

```
//Custom exception for process task after timeout
public class TaskTimeoutException : TimeoutException
{
    public Task task { get; }
    public TaskTimeoutException(Task task)
        => this.task = task;
}

private static async Task WaitSyncFunction(Action syncFunction,
    int timeoutMilliseconds,
    CancellationToken token)
{
    var syncFunctionTask = Task.Run(syncFunction);
    var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeoutMilliseconds, token);
    await Task.WhenAny(timeoutTask, syncFunctionTask);//.ContinueWith(task =>
    //{ //Unnecessary ContinueWith
    //if (timeoutTask.IsCanceled) throw new TaskCanceledException();
    //return the function task so that it can do something else after it ending
    if (timeoutTask.IsCanceled) throw new TaskCanceledException(syncFunctionTask);
    //if (timeoutTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully) throw new TimeoutException();
    //return the function task so that it can do something else after it ending
    if (timeoutTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully) throw new TaskTimeoutException(syncFunctionTask);
    if (syncFunctionTask.IsFaulted) throw syncFunctionTask.Exception.InnerException;
    //});
}
```

Comment: Have you read [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations/)?

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. There really isn't enough code here to review. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @PeterCsala I've read it but I think it may not much fit for me, in my code it support 4 status: Canceled, Faulted, Timeout and Complated. but the code in article is only support 3 status: Canceled, Faulted and Complated. If i want to add timeout I need add a Task to achieve. I think it's not a good idea. (CancelAfter also not a good idea, it will be think as Canceled, not Timeout)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever we have an async method and we want to differentiate `Canceled` from `Timeout` then we usually do the following:

1. We are anticipating `OperationCanceledException` (the base class of `TaskCanceledException`)
2. We examine the `IsCancellationRequested` property of the `CancellationToken`

Let me show you a simple example:

#### `Timeout`

```cs
private static readonly TimeSpan OperationDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
// timeoutSource will be triggered
private static readonly TimeSpan Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2); 
private static readonly TimeSpan CancelAfter = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var userCancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource(CancelAfter);
    try
    {
        await TestAsync(userCancellationSource.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(userCancellationSource.IsCancellationRequested ? "Canceled" : "Timed out");
    }
}

public static async Task TestAsync(CancellationToken token = default)
{
    var timeoutSource = new CancellationTokenSource(Timeout);
    var timeoutOrCancellationSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(timeoutSource.Token, token);
    await Task.Delay(OperationDuration, timeoutOrCancellationSource.Token);
}
```

#### `Canceled`

```cs
private static readonly TimeSpan OperationDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
private static readonly TimeSpan Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2); 
// userCancellationSource will be triggered 
private static readonly TimeSpan CancelAfter = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1); 

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var userCancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource(CancelAfter);
    try
    {
        await TestAsync(userCancellationSource.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(userCancellationSource.IsCancellationRequested ? "Canceled" : "Timed out");
    }
}

public static async Task TestAsync(CancellationToken token = default)
{
    var timeoutSource = new CancellationTokenSource(Timeout);
    var timeoutOrCancellationSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(timeoutSource.Token, token);
    await Task.Delay(OperationDuration, timeoutOrCancellationSource.Token);
}
```

I think the same pattern should be followed by your wrapper. To have the same behavior I have modified your `WaitSyncFunction` method in the following way

```cs
private static async Task WaitSyncFunction(Action syncFunction, int timeoutMilliseconds, CancellationToken token)
{
    var syncFunctionTask = Task.Run(syncFunction);
    var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeoutMilliseconds, token);
    await Task.WhenAny(timeoutTask, syncFunctionTask);
    if (timeoutTask.IsCanceled) token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); //changed
    if (timeoutTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully) throw new OperationCanceledException(token); //changed
    if (syncFunctionTask.IsFaulted) throw syncFunctionTask.Exception.InnerException;
}
```

#### `Timeout`

```cs
private static readonly TimeSpan OperationDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
// timeoutSource will be triggered
private static readonly TimeSpan Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
private static readonly TimeSpan CancelAfter = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var userCancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource(CancelAfter);
    try
    {
        await WaitSyncFunction(() => Thread.Sleep((int) OperationDuration.TotalMilliseconds),
            (int) Timeout.TotalMilliseconds, userCancellationSource.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(userCancellationSource.IsCancellationRequested ? "Canceled" : "Timed out");
    }
}

private static async Task WaitSyncFunction(Action syncFunction, int timeoutMilliseconds,
    CancellationToken token)
{
    var syncFunctionTask = Task.Run(syncFunction);
    var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeoutMilliseconds, token);
    await Task.WhenAny(timeoutTask, syncFunctionTask);
    if (timeoutTask.IsCanceled) token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    if (timeoutTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully) throw new OperationCanceledException(token);
    if (syncFunctionTask.IsFaulted) throw syncFunctionTask.Exception.InnerException;
}
```

#### `Canceled`

```cs
private static readonly TimeSpan OperationDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
private static readonly TimeSpan Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
// userCancellationSource will be triggered 
private static readonly TimeSpan CancelAfter = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var userCancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource(CancelAfter);
    try
    {
        await WaitSyncFunction(() => Thread.Sleep((int) OperationDuration.TotalMilliseconds),
            (int) Timeout.TotalMilliseconds, userCancellationSource.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(userCancellationSource.IsCancellationRequested ? "Canceled" : "Timed out");
    }
}

private static async Task WaitSyncFunction(Action syncFunction, int timeoutMilliseconds,
    CancellationToken token)
{
    var syncFunctionTask = Task.Run(syncFunction);
    var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeoutMilliseconds, token);
    await Task.WhenAny(timeoutTask, syncFunctionTask);
    if (timeoutTask.IsCanceled) token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    if (timeoutTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully) throw new OperationCanceledException(token);
    if (syncFunctionTask.IsFaulted) throw syncFunctionTask.Exception.InnerException;
}
```

---

Please bear in mind that with this implementation the `syncFunction` is not aborted in case of timeout. To support cooperative cancellation you have to pass the `CancellationToken` to the `syncFunction` and examine its `IsCancellationRequested` property periodically (at each checkpoint / milestone).

Check out these for more details:

- [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads)
- [CodeReview topic: C# asynchronous tasks training (turn-based simulation)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256168/c-asynchronous-tasks-training-turn-based-simulation)

Comment: If I want to do something process after the "MySyncFunction" end (complated or faulted), I should write a override`... WaitSyncFunction(Task syncFunctionTask, ...)` and create the task of sync function before calling? (Throw a exception with a task looks weird indeed)

Comment: @Squirrel.Downy To be honest with you I'm not sure I've understood your question 100%, could you please rephrase it. If you want to execute something after completion then call it after your `await WaitSyncFunction( ...);` inside the `try` block. If you want to execute something in case of failure then call it inside the `catch` block.